# Get Laravel Dusk to Run Properly on Ubuntu 16 wt Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-dusk, laravel-dusk2

I've been trying to integrate Laravel Dusk into my testing scheme for a week and can't get any test to actually deliver expected results. Here's the situation:

- I'm running Laravel 55 on Homestead (per Project install) with php 7.1.*
- I installed Dusk following the installation steps in the docs.

Out of the box the tests didn't work

- I added the steps found in [this article on "Laravel Dusk on Homestead"](https://medium.com/@splatEric/laravel-dusk-on-homestead-dc5711987595) and the gist found [here in "setup-headless-selenium-xvfb.sh"](https://gist.github.com/alonisser/11192482) this to my provisioning file. This removed a lot of the exceptions I was getting.
- I also added all my existing environment vars to the php node of my  `phpunit.dusk.xml` file exactly as they were done so in the already successfully running phpunit tests from `phpunit.xml`

However now when I run the tests I just can't get the expected output. This is what I am doing. I add an input field in my home page ('/') view file as such: `<input id="dusk-test" value="1234">`

I run this test which is a mod of the original example test and is the only test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;

class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser)
        {
            $browser->visit('/')->refresh()
                ->assertValue('#dusk-test', '1234')
            ;
        });
    }
}
```

...by running `php artisan dusk` and this is my output EVERY time

```
PHPUnit 6.4.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E                                                                   1 
/ 1 (100%)

Time: 1.07 seconds, Memory: 12.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: 
Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"dusk-test"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=62.0.3202.62)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498513 (2c63aa53b2c658de596ed550eb5267ec5967b351),platform=Linux 4.4.0-92-generic x86_64)


  /home/vagrant/landing/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php:102 /home/vagrant/landing/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:320
  /home/vagrant/landing/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:535
  /home/vagrant/landing/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:175
  /home/vagrant/landing/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/ElementResolver.php:281
  /home/vagrant/landing/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/ElementResolver.php:327
  /home/vagrant/landing/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/MakesAssertions.php:632
  /home/vagrant/landing/tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php:22
  /home/vagrant/landing/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/TestCase.php:92
  /home/vagrant/landing/tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php:24

  ERRORS!
  Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

To make this even more confusing, this is my output when I dump from the test. Here's how I dump

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;

class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic browser test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser)
        {
            $browser->visit('/')
                ->dump()
            ;
        });
    }
}
```

and my output after running `php artisan dusk` again is

```
PHPUnit 6.4.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

"<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>"
```

Which is absolutely NOT my homepage. I also dumped the `$url` value from `vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Browser.php` and got my projects correct `APP_URL`.

I'm at a loss. Dusk is being sent the right location and the page definitely has the input and value. But, I can't get Dusk to give the expected output which would be that 12345 was retrieved from the element.

All help appreciated.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I could even verify through chromedriver debugging, that chrome is directed to the correct endpoints and returns the correct data.

Comment: Is it a HTTPS site? (BTW: You shouldn't need Selenium and Xvfb anymore.)

Comment: It is not a https site. I'm currently not using Selenium, but am still starting up an Xvfb session. Is that not necessary anymore?
As I mentioned before, everything from dusk instructing webdriver to chrome navigating and rendering pages is working. The content of the page is lost between webdriver and dusk.

Comment: With headless Chrome you don't need it anymore. What do the logs say (`console` directory)? Does it work with a site like google.com?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, someone has an update on this?

Comment: @ChukkyNzw were you able to fix this issue? please help!

Answer (score 3):

maybe what i'm saying is wrong ... but Laravel dusk seems to need `dusk` instead of `id`: like `dusk="dusk-test"`. also call it after :
`$browser->visit('/')>refresh()
->assertValue('@dusk-test', '1234')` and it should be like the doc.

Comment: not really, im' juste suggesting. but when u see this: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"dusk-test"} and read the doc, it looks like the error come from here.

Comment: The thing is, if I look at the screenshot, it's entirely blank. If I dump the response, it is: <html><head></head><body></body></html>. So no elements to be found.

Answer (score 0):

On [Github](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/480) someone solved his problem by replacing `https://` with `http://`
in the `.env` file.